# Using background.js with popup.html

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

**popup.js**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  document.body.innerHTML = '<div class="mydiv"><img src="loading.gif"/></div>';
  // document.body.style.backgroundColor = '#F5F5F5';
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = '#FAFAFA';
  document.body.style.borderRadius = '4px';
  var span = document.createElement('span');
  span.innerHTML = 'Processing';
  span.style.position = 'relative';
  span.style.left = 'auto';
  span.style.right = 'auto';
  span.style.width = '100%';
  span.style.textAlign = 'center'
  span.style.display = 'inline-block';
  span.style.fontSize = '30px';
  document.querySelector('.mydiv').appendChild(span);
});
```

---

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Note Parser",

  "description": "This extension demonstrates a 'browser action'.",

  "version": "2.0",

  "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches": [ "file:///*" ],
        "js": ["pie.js"]
      }
  ],

  "browser_action": {
      "default_icon": "icon.png",
      "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },

  "background": {
      "scripts": ["background.js"],
      "persistent": false
  },

  "permissions": ["activeTab" /*is the default permission*/ ]
}
```

---

**popup.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Note Parser</title>
    <style>
      body {
        min-width: 350px;
      }
      .mydiv {
        font-family: "Segoe UI";
        font-size: 12px;
        background-color: #FFF;
        padding: 6px;
        margin: 4px;
        height: 250px;
        min-height: 50px;
        border-radius: 3px;
        border: 1px solid #E0E0E0;
        color: #444;
      }
      img {
        margin: auto auto;
        top: 0px;
        bottom: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        right: 0px;
        position: absolute;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

---

**background.js**

```
alert('Out');
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  alert('In');
  // No tabs or host permissions needed!
  console.log('Turning ' + tab.url + ' red!');
  chrome.tabs.executeScript({
    code: 'document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";'
  });
});
```

[image: Reloading a Chrome ext. in the developer mode.]

I'm experiencing a weird issue with my Chrome ext. code. It has the following files (as shown above) -

1. popup.js
2. manifest.json
3. popup.html
4. background.js

The issue is that the code inside the block `chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {` does not execute :(

`alert('Out');` gets executed when I reload the ext., but, when I return back to the tab with URL *file:///D:/Users/username/Desktop/file.html* and then click the ext. icon, `alert('In');` doesn't get executed.

Additionally, I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15194198/background-js-not-working-chrome-extension) that

> Do you have default_popup in your manifest? if so the code will not
>   work!

which has completely confused me... as if that were the case, the first alert won't execute; or maybe I am wrong. Please help me do this correctly.

Comment: You can either specify a `default_popup` OR listen for `browserAction.onClicked`, not both. If you have a `default_popup`, the `onClicked` event is never fired, so your listener is never called.