# Google Chrome Extension toggle icon

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create a little chrome extension with a toggleable icon ("active" and "inactive") and a pupup-page. The icon should be active, when the popup is shown and inactive, when the popup is hidden.
I am allready able to toggle the Icon on click using the background-script, just like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16136524/3182091).
But unfortunately this doesn't work, if you have a `default_popup`-page, as the `browser_action` catches the `clickEvent` and the background-script does not get notified.
So my question is, how can i toggle the icon while using a `default_popup`-page?

**EDIT:**
The problem i have is, that the `chrome.browserAction.onClicked` method is not called, when you have a `default_popup` (it is also said in the comments to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15195401/3182091)). So i need something else to get notified, if the extension was clicked or not...

Comment: Show your code, so far it seems you did something wrong because there are no such restrictions on changing the icon.

Comment: @wOxxOm the problem is not changing the icon, but the `clickEvent`. As described [in the comments of this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15195401/3182091), the `chrome.browserAction.onClicked` is not fired, when a `default_popup` exists...

Comment: Ah, I see! Then what about simply changing the icon in the popup script on start and change it back in `onbeforeunload`?

Comment: `onbeforeunload`? Never heard about that, but it sounds like a possible solution. I am still new to extension development so i did not know about that. I'll try that soon. Thanks!

Comment: @wOxxOm tryed it yesterday and it worked with `unload`. Basicly i made a function `toggle` inside the `background.js` and called it, when the `popup.html` has been loaded. Also i add a `EventListener` for "unload"` to the `popup.js`, which calls `toggle` for the `background.js`. Unfortunately, i have seen, that the popup closes, when it looses focus, so i can't really use it for my case. But thats a different story. Please write an answer to this question so i can mark it as accepted.

Comment: My idea was different and nonworking because Chrome apparently doesn't call `window.onbeforeunload` in the popups.

Comment: @wOxxOm yea, i saw that, while searching for the documentation of `onbeforeunload` and there i also found the solution using `unload` instead.